# How to disable visual C++ memory leak checking for a particular file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks

One of my projects is making use of Microsoft's supplied memory leak checker via `_CrtSetDbgFlag` etc. This is working fine except that I now want to make use of a third-party package which is leaking a small amount of memory. I have no particular need to fix the leaks, but the output is annoying since it will disguise "genuine" leaks that may be introduced.

How does one go about disabling this leak checking for a particular file or project, but leave it on for others? My understanding is that it gets enabled via some `#define` in debug mode - I've had a bit of a fiddle but haven't managed to find something which I can `#undef` to switch it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deactive the heap allocation checker in the concerned files by use of _CrtSetDbgFlag() and the macro `_CRTDBG_CHECK_DEFAULT_DF` (which is equal to `0`) before the first `new` instruction in a file where you don't want to check memory leaks and reactive it just after the `new` instructions. See MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Another way only for **MFC projects:**
I personally use the `DEBUG_NEW` macro to detect memory leaks. In each file of my project I have added the macro. If you don't put the macro in a file, memory leaks will not be found in it but only in the others. The macro is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz7sxz99.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - flipping the flag on and off works great. I'd gotten too hung up on that having been set and trying to evade the changes to new. It's not a MFC project so the DEBUG_NEW thing doesn't apply in this case, but nice to know anyway :)